# How to safely evaluate simple Python expressions, e.g. from HTTP GET arguments?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Is there a native way of doing safe evaluation of simple Python expressions like those in:

```
a = ['None', 'False', '0', '0.0', '"s"', '(0,)', '[0,]']
```

These may for example be provided by HTTP GET like:

```
http://...?alfa=1&bravo=True&delta=1.0&charlie="s"&echo=None
```

The result of the evaluation should be Python types like `None`, `bool`, `int`, `float`, `str`, etc.

Evaluation using Python `eval` would be the obvious starting point, but since `eval` is unsafe, it can't be used directly for evaluating arguments from HTTP GET.

What is a good way to do safe evaluation of simple Python expressions?

Comment: Although the duplicated post answers the question as posted, you should really consider using JSON for this usecase instead. JSON parsing happens to be faster as well.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquezAbrams: Thanks for the duplicate reference; [ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) was exactly what I was looking for.  Would like to given you an upvote and correct answer for the duplicate reference ;-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for pointing to JSON; in this case I need it for parsing of HTTP GET arguments, but I see the point in using JSON elsewhere.

Comment: JSON is perfectly usable in URL query parameters too! :-) `alfa=1&bravo=true&delta=1.0&charlie="s"&echo=null` is the JSON equivalent for just the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` values, or you could use `{"alfa":1,"bravo":true,"delta":1.0,"charlie":"s","echo":null}` as the query string to go JSON all the way.